# Angular http get use absolute url instead of relative url

Tags: angularjs, get, relative-path, absolute-path, relative-url

just trying this:

```
var baseurl = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api";
var request = $http.get(baseurl);

request.success(function(html) {
    $log.log(html);
});

request.error(function(html) {
    $log.log(html);
});
```

but angular keeps prefixing it with `http://localhost/` why does it use the relative url? how can I change it to use absolute url.

Comment: Have you tried the non-shorthand version (`$http(config)`)?

Comment: no but I just tried this: var request = $http.get('http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api'); but I got a CORS error...I know how to fix CORS errors when if the server side was mine, but this is external...

Comment: Then there's pretty much nothing you can do about it from the client-side.

Comment: @Shomz yes, um, I'll try some other stuff

Comment: @Shomz jsonp worked, thank you :)

Comment: How did you use JSONP here to get it to work? I'm flustered trying it myself.